# How to change PhpStorm software appearance font

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've successfully changed coding font in PhpStorm settings but I cannot change software appearance font such as software menu and etc.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance`
2. `UI Options --> Override default fonts by`

[image]

Comment: @mahdipishguy What do you mean by "I do not have"? Your screenshot clearly shows that you do (it's taken from the same settings page as mine).

Comment: i try to find `Override default fonts by`  and select other font from combox like with your screen shot